# What technique can I use to test my code when code renders out an untestable(?) PDF document?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing

I have a need to test output of my code before I send the output for PDF rendering.

Currently I have decided on a switch statement that does two different things depending on whether I am in production or in testing mode.

1. Render PDF with data that goes on PDF in a web browser.  Nothing is returned to caller
2. Do not render the PDF but just return the data for test/other purposes

Just to show some code to clarify ...  Here is what I have now:

```
$output = $this->prepOutputData();
switch ($this->strategy)
{
    //outputs binary PDF, no return statement
    case OutlineStrategy::PDF_STRATEGY:
        $pdfEngine = new PdfEngine();

        $em = DoctrineConnector::getEntityManager();
        $metaData = $em->getRepository(PdfMetadata::class)->findAll();

        $pdfEngine->arrangeDataOnPdf($metaData, $output);
        $pdfEngine->printPdfToBrowser();
        break;

    //returns data that goes onto PDF 
    //for testing or for consumption by non-PDF entity
    case OutlineStrategy::TEST_STRATEGY:
        return $output;
        break;
}
```

**Goal**

My goal is to be able to show PDF in production but NOT show PDF for testing and yet to be able to run test checks on the `$output` data.  How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you have such radically different interfaces for what is conceptually the same operation?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean.... are you saying displaying a binary PDF and returning an array is the same operation?  What do you suggest instead?  I can see perhaps I can just return data in both cases, but somehow, somewhere I do need to render out the PDF.  How to do that is my goal for this question.  How do I switch from production and testing modes without having to modify code (code should be able to run both production and test modes).

Comment: The strategy pattern is if you have one (conceptual) operation that can be performed in several ways (for example, showing data in either a PDF or a word document). Showing a PDF and returning the raw data to the caller seem like two completely different operations in two different functions.

Comment: If verifying the PDF in test mode is a bottleneck for you, you could choose to render the data as a simple text document in that case in test mode and as PDF in production mode.

Comment: I could do that yes.  But do I need to be using this pattern at all?  For example, I can set up my tests in such as way that they test the `$output` before it is sent to PDF Engine. That way I may not need a Strategy at all, but instead set up my test code to call appropriate methods to retrieve $output before it is sent off to the `PdfEngine`.  For example I use do set up a `$runAsTest` flag, and then `if ($runAsTest) return $output;`  I do not need a text document.  I need to be able to test my `$output` as correct, before it is printed, via PDF, or text, or otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Separating `getOutput($input)` from `generateOutline($input)` and testing whether `getOutput($input)` returns the correct results is an important step.

If the generated pdf requires testing you can test:

- Is the generated PDF a valid PDF: via tools such as [Apache PDFBox](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi8j_6OrdbJAhWEiQ8KHYTdBj8QFggqMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpdfbox.apache.org%2F1.8%2Fcookbook%2Fpdfavalidation.html&usg=AFQjCNEvEYDpVOvv7tl9y5fAMGWGtjxZQg&sig2=b1suU5T9eTlvRV_rLVRb_Q) (this one is in Java but PHP equivalents do probabably exist) or an online validation tool.
- Does the generated PDF contain the expected data: using tools such as [pdf_search](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwidjqyvsNbJAhXBoQ4KHXl7B_AQFggfMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.phpclasses.org%2Fpackage%2F702-PHP-Searches-pdf-documents-for-text.html&usg=AFQjCNH_eMWGT8ICOdNSY4DtJWBf_2e4LA&sig2=u9eli_Paca1gs8ENSWQiKw&bvm=bv.109910813,d.ZWU), see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/1882318/814206.

Automatically testing the UX part of testing the generated PDF is more difficult (I don't know whether tools for these tests exist).:

- Is the PDF readable?
- Is the layout correct?
- Does is follow typesetting best practices?

Answer (score 1):

I removed strategy constructs (OutlineStrategy::PDF_STRATEGY, etc) out of my code.  Then rewrote code to use services.

I will test services and not the PDF generation.  aka PDF Generation will be untested, but the processes leading up to it will be tested.

Per Doc Brown wrote a function just for testing output.

```
public function generateOutline($input)
{
    $output = $this->getOutput($input);
    $this->pdfService->renderPdf($output);
}

public function testOutput($input)
{
    return $this->getOutput($input);
}

private function getOutput($input)
{
    $data = $this->inputFilter->getOutlineRequestData($input);
    $output = $this->processor->processInput($data);
    return $output;
}
```

Notice `public/private` modifiers